# Twilio Notify Endpoint

Tags: twilio

I am a bit confused with how Twilio's Notify service is supposed to work.

From what I understand for server-side binding
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/guides/register-for-notifications-ios

- Identity - Unique User Identifier
- BindingType - APN or FCM
- Address - Token Provided by device

Endpoint ? 
I am a bit confused by what endpoint is supposed to be? Can someone provide an example of what the endpoint should be?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The endpoint is a unique identifier created by Twilio and returned to you when you create a binding.

It represents an instance of a device which is associated with an identity and is used to prevent duplicate bindings if the device token changes.

I know nothing about iOS development, so have no idea what triggers a token change, whether device tokens are permanently linked to specific hardware, or assigned and reassigned by Apple on some basis.